# advanced options in word is stuck automatically selecting entire word though the default checkbox is not checked

Tags: microsoft-word, editing, bug

I cannot stop word from always selecting an entire word when editing. I have unchecked the default checkbox that enables this by default in the advanced setting editing options, but it still automatically selects the entire word. Is there another fix?

Comment: Do you mean when you use mouse to select text from the middle of one word to the another one, the entire first word in which you originally clicked is selected? If yes, I suggest you rename your Normal.dotm, or try to [reset Word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/word/reset-options-and-settings-in-word).

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific.

[image: screenshot]

How are you selecting the text? Double-click will always select a complete Word.